# c++ write()/read() buffer type not working

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

I am writing a project using forks and pipes in c++ in Visual Studio Code and when i write the code

```
int temptotal;
write(fds[1],temptotal,sizeof(int));
```

or

```
read(fds[0],temptotal,sizeof(int));
```

I get red underlines on the temptotal variable, saying:
'argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *"'

I can provide more details on the project if necessary, but I believe it is only this individual aspect that is having issues, as everything else works as expected, but I am unable to read() and write() between child and parent. I assumed that const void * would allow me to pass any type, but I am clearly misunderstanding something. I am using Visual Studio Code using the g++ compiler.

Comment: An `int` is not a pointer.

Comment: At least you may read the [linux write() doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).`temptotal` should be a buffer to read from, writting in the file `fds[1]`

Comment: "I am writing a project using forks and pipes in c++" - Remember that pipes are not a standardized thing. Pipes in Windows and Linux (for example) are different things and have different APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a *pointer* to the memory where `write` should write and `read` should read:

```c
write(fds[1], &temptotal, sizeof temptotal);
//            ^
read(fds[0], &temptotal, sizeof temptotal);
//           ^
```